# How to pass props data between two functional components

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to use a props value in other component but being new to react I am not able to do so .

I am having these two functional components in same file

```
const actionMarkup = ({ unique_id }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ClientTaskLink taskId={unique_id}>
        <ViewButton />
      </ClientTaskLink>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) 
const ClientTaskIndex = ({tasks, toggleCompleted, showCompleted,clientId}) => {
        return(
            <div className="component">
            <SortTable columns={columns} clientId={clientId} data={tasks} actions={actionMarkup} defaultSort="start_time" defaultDirection="desc" />
            <div className="list-actions">
              <a href="#" onClick={toggleCompleted}>{`${ showCompleted ? 'Hide' : 'View' } Completed Tasks`}</a>
            </div>
            <style jsx>{`
              .list-actions {
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 30px;
                font-weight: bold;
              }
            `}</style>
          </div>
        ) 
}
    export default ClientTaskIndex;
```

There is a prop in **ClientTaskIndex** component i.e. **clientId** and I want to use this in **actionMarkup**. Please help it wasted a lot of time already. I have tried to use directly but not working.

Comment: What is this `SortTable` component that you are using? What does it do to the component passed in `actions`?

Comment: actionmarkup is passed to this Sortable component

Comment: I can pass clientId to this but other components are also using this and when I use it shown clientid is not a prop in other places

Comment: Have you tried `actions={<ActionMarkup unique_id={id} />}`?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings it shows ActionMarkup is not defined

Comment: Use a capital `A` in your component, all components should start with a capital letter

Comment: where i was using actionmarkup it through error that it is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two options to manage this:

1. Using HOC (high order component): This is a kind of component that will wrap both **actionMarkup** and **ClientTaskIndex** and hold all props shared between this two components. Thus, it will be easy to get the necessary props from HOC.
   https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
2. Using a state container as Redux: https://redux.js.org/

Comment: I need a solution

Answer (score 1):

HOC option:

```
const HocComponent = ({ clientId }) => (
 <div>
    <ClientTaskLink clientId={clientId}>
    <ActionMarkup clientId={clientId}>
  </div>
);


const ActionMarkup = ({ unique_id, clientId }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ClientTaskLink taskId={unique_id}>
        <ViewButton />
      </ClientTaskLink>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) 
const ClientTaskIndex = ({tasks, toggleCompleted, showCompleted,clientId}) => {
        return(
            <div className="component">
            <SortTable columns={columns} clientId={clientId} data={tasks} actions={actionMarkup} defaultSort="start_time" defaultDirection="desc" />
            <div className="list-actions">
              <a href="#" onClick={toggleCompleted}>{`${ showCompleted ? 'Hide' : 'View' } Completed Tasks`}</a>
            </div>
            <style jsx>{`
              .list-actions {
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 30px;
                font-weight: bold;
              }
            `}</style>
          </div>
        ) 
}

export default HocComponent;
```

Comment: will this affect some functionality or now clientId will be available

Comment: which functionality ?

Comment: the functionalities which Sortable is providing